# iOS app stops receiving notifications when reconnected to internet

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a weird problem, I send notifications via FCM to topics in iOS devices.

Sometimes **when the device is connected to slow internet or no internet**, and **then connects back to the internet**, all notification sent prior are not received, and new sent notifications after will be delayed!

**For example:** A device would be connected back to internet all is fine but I receive the notification delayed 10min and when I receive it the very first moment it's shown, it will say in the dialog: 10min ago!

**If I restart the iPhone after that, everything will be fixed again!** and I can receive notifications normally.
This issue happened to me in two different devices so I am sure its not from the phone. and other apps notifications would be working without problem as well.

I am thinking **maybe its something wrong with my fcm notification configurations** that I send from the server, can anyone point if I am missing something here.

**Message configuration:**

```
$message = CloudMessage::fromArray([
    "condition" => $the_conditions,
    "notification" => [
        "title" => $title,
        "body" => $body,
    ],
    "data" => $data_passed,
    //Apple:
    "apns" => [
        "headers" => [
            "apns-priority" => "10",
        ],
        "payload" => [
            "aps" => [
                "alert" => [
                    "title" => $title,
                    "body" => $body,
                ],
                "sound" => $sound,
                "thread-id" => "thread_$item_id"
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I require high availability notifications that need to be sent immediately.

Note: I am using a php library to send the notification from server: [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of the SDK you're using

Firstly, the message you composed is perfectly fine, there's nothing wrong with it.

In the context of the SDK I regularly receive issue reports about FCM messages being delivered with big delays or not at all, and unfortunately, there's no way to check if and when a message has been delivered from an Admin SDK. If you send a message to Firebase and Firebase doesn't respond with an error (e.g. when the payload is invalid, when a device token is not registered or when the server is unavailable), we have to assume that the delivery was successful.

To ensure highly reliable messages I currently see two ways how you could achieve that:

1. Use another messaging service that promises highly reliable delivery like e.g https://pushy.me/ (this is not a recommendation, I'm not affiliated to Pushy and have never used it)
2. When sending a message from your backend server, include a transaction ID in the `data` payload, and store it in a database. From the receiving client, issue a request back to your backend server to confirm the message reception. This way you could see if and when a message has been confirmed and can re-send it after a defined amount of time. This has some drawbacks of course - perhaps the client received the message, but the confirmation call failed, or messages could still be sent twice. It's just a naive idea from the top of my head

Comment: Thank you Jerome for the recommendation and for creating a great SDK  I honestly believe the issue is neither with the SDK nor with FCM, because when a device is not receiving a notification for the mentioned bug occuring, other devices on the same topic will receive successfully. I added today `apns-expiration` & `apns-push-type` to my apns header and going to test further. Its really hard to recreate the bug so lets see 

Comment: any updates on this iam also not getting push when device comes to online after offline

Comment: @ChinjuJames nothing for now what I discovered work best is to set `apns-expiration` to a timestamp that ends in an hour for example. that reduce the issue. The library I am using RNFB release a big update last month and I am going to test further if its fixed in my app.